# Extract day and hour from a datetime column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has a datetime column:

```
Date
2020-01-01 00:00:00
...
2020-02-29 23:45:00
```

How can convert this to the format:

```
Date
2020-01-01 0
...
2020-02-29 23
```

I tried: `df['hour'] = df['Date'].dt.day+ " "+df['Date'].dt.hour` but this lets to:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and
>   'str'

Comment: Dumb question, but is `df['Date']` 100% a datetime?. try `df['Date'].dtype`

Comment: use `dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')`

Comment: @MattR the dytpe is: datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dt.strftime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')

0    2020-01-01 00
1    2020-02-29 23
Name: Date, dtype: object
```